# Jinja2Templates TemplateNotFound and Docker

Tags: python, docker, jinja2, fastapi

My directory sturcture:

```
.
|--app
|   |--__init__.py
|   |--main.py
|   |--templates
|        |--index.html
|  
|--Dockerfile
|--requirements.txt
```

When I try to access this at localhost, I get the following error:
`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /code/app/templates/index.html`

In `main.py` I have the following lines of relevant code:

```
...
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="/code/app/templates/static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="/code/app/templates")
...
@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("/code/app/templates/index.html", {"request": request}
```

How do I allow the path to index.html path to be seen by main?

**Dockerfile**
My Dockerfile follows the example given by FastAPI pretty closely.

```
FROM python:3.10.1

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

ENV PYTHONPATH /code

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

The run command is `docker run -d --name testcon -p 80:80 testimage`

Comment: You usually give the template relative to the base directory. Here it would be just `index.html`.

Comment: This is what I was originally doing and it gave me the same error.

Comment: You have a couple of hints that you might be running this inside a Docker container; if you are, how are you creating the image and running it (edit the question to include your Dockerfile and the `docker run` command)?  Does it work outside of Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze That's correct. I've updated my question to include the Dockerfile and run command.

Comment: @extDependency Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try logging into your container to see what the actual path is and then use that.

```
docker ps -a  # will give you the container id
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash # you are inside the container

pwd # you get the current directory from your Dockerfile it looks like it will be /code
```

You don't need all the above commands to figure this out. You can just read the Dockerfile and figure it out. The above commands are to make sure that the file is there.

The path will be `templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="/code/app/templates")`

and
   `return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request}`

The following line is not needed

`app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="/code/app/templates/static"), name="static")`